Test Helm chart with Minikube in GitLab CI
I am developing an Helm chart, and I would like to deploy and test it using GitLab CI. I have a self-hosted runner configured with a docker executor. The job uses a custom image that contains some tools that I need for the test (like kubectl, helm, ct and others), but for some reason I cannot seem to make Minikube work
The goal is to run a Minikube cluster within the docker executor. I don't need it to be persistent or performant, as the tests are quite light.
No matter what, I always get the same error: /usr/bin/minikube: cannot execute: required file not found
Things I've tried:

Install Minikube in the custom image

Initially I was using an ubuntu-based dind image, which gave me problems with systemd and cgroups, so I switched to the base docker image
minikube is installed as per documentation, directly from the binary


Install Minikube as part of the pipeline, by adding the curl and install command as steps of the job
Using docker:dind as service in the job, both with and without the DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375 variable

Also tried to set the DOCKER_HOST variable to unix:///var/run/docker.sock to try run the minikube containers on the host itself



